# find the key with longest path from the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, return-value

find the key with longest path from the dictionary. The key value pair will be integers. consider the following dictionary d={2:1,3:2,4:5,1:4}
here the first key is 2 and its value is 1. so you need to find the value of key 1. this method has to follow until the value is not present in the dictionary as a key or the value become the key where we start to traverse the dictionary

i tried like this :

```
    d = {2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 5, 1: 4}
    k = 0
    count = 0


    def find(k):
      m = d[k]
      return m


    for i in d.keys():
          k = d[i]
          find(k)
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

my aim pass the each to function and return

Comment: i dont know how to do it

Comment: @VysakhPv `I dont know how to do it` usually means you're thinking too big. Instead of trying to think through the whole assignment, just try to think of the first step you need to take.

Comment: i am learner still i tried to d[i] iteration it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome on board, @VysakhPv :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right, this is the functionality you require:

d = {2:1, 3:2, 4:5, 1:4}

so if 
key = 2, value = 1;
key = 1, value = 4;
key = 4, value = 5;
key = 5 --> No value so stop here

**Thus to find the key with the longest path:**

```
d={2:1,3:2,4:5,1:4}
c1=0
ans_key = -1
for i in d.keys():
    k=i
    c=0
    while(k in d.keys()):
        k = d[k]
        c+=1
    if(c1<c):
        c1=c
        ans_key=i
print("The Key with the longest path is",ans_key)
```

This will return the output:

> The Key with the longest path is 3

Hope this helps!